# 0.Finding 2 sets A and B(belong to R) that SupA = SupB, infA=infB and a=!b for all a and all b

Tags: limits, supremum-and-infimum, infinity

I try to find simple example and as many as I can and the only one im thinking of is arctan(x)
-π/2--> π/2
and then i dont know how to make A and B from it

edit:

Let A={$\frac{m^2-n}{m^2+n^2}: n,m \in \mathbb{N}, m>n $} n and m odd

Let B={$\frac{m^2-n}{m^2+n^2}: n,m \in \mathbb{N}, m>n$}n and m even

probably good enough becuase Sup =1 for both and inf = 1/2 for both but is it has to be that hard?

edit2: no the sups arn't good

edit3:
Let A={$a\in Q | 1<a<3 $}

Let B={$b\in R/Q | 1<b<3 $}

so $a{\displaystyle \neq b  } $    for every a b and supA=supB=3, infA=infB=1

Comment: "group" has a precise definition in mathematics, but I don't think you intend that.  I think you mean "set of real numbers" or something like that.  If so, just think about rationals vs irrationals or the like.

Comment: Groups of A B that belong to R

Comment: As lulu said, I don't think "group" is the word you're looking for. Of course, this is an understandable mistake (you're not the first person to make it, and you won't be the last). But it is a mistake that should be corrected. Maybe you meant "set".

Comment: I don't know the diffrence. in my language it translates to groups

Comment: Please correct the term, your use of it is very misleading.  "set" will do.  And, again, to your problem:  think about rationals vs irrationals (or any other pair of non-intersecting dense sets)

Comment: ok no problem would do.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use your idea of using the $\arctan$ function. In particular, we'll use the fact that it's a strictly increasing function with limits $\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ at $\pm\infty$. Indeed consider the sets

$$A=\{\arctan(2k):k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$

and

$$B=\{\arctan(2k+1):k\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$

It may or may not be intuitively clear why these work, but let's prove it regardless.

We start by showing that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, i.e. that they have no elements in common. Suppose, for a contradiction, that they did, i.e. that there is some $x$ such that $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Then, as $x\in A$, we can write

$$a=\arctan(2k)$$

for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, but similarly, as $x\in B$, we can also write

$$a=\arctan(2m+1)$$

for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. But as $\arctan$ is injective, this would mean that $2k=2m+1$, which is a contradiction, as an integer cannot be both even and odd. Thus $A$ and $B$ are disjoint sets.

Let's now prove that $\sup A=\sup B=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Firstly, as $\arctan(\mathbb{R})=\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, it is clear that $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is an upper bound of both $A$ and $B$. We show now that there is no smaller upper bound of $A$ (an almost identical argument can be used for $B$). Suppose for a contradiction that $A$ had a smaller upper bound $\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$. As $\arctan(2k)\to\frac{\pi}{2}$ as $k\to\infty$, we can find a $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\arctan(2k)>\alpha$ (this is just using the definition of the limit). But as $\arctan(2k)\in A$, this contradicts that $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $A$. Now just repeat the argument for $B$.

We have thus shown that $\sup A=\sup B=\frac{\pi}{2}$. An almost identical argument shows that $\inf A=\inf B=-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Of course there are a lot of other example you could make of this, some of which use, for example, the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, but as we've shown, those are not the only examples.

Comment: are there more solutions like the arctan(odd)/arctan(even) ?

Comment: @gilgil Pick 1) Any two unbounded, disjoint sets of real numbers, 2) any bounded, injective function on the real numbers that has limits towards both infinities Put the two sets through the function, and it should automatically work exactly like this.

Comment: Correction: bounded, injective function that has its upper and lower bounds as limits towards $\pm\infty$. A continuous, injective, bounded function, such as $\arctan$ or $\tanh$ would work, for instance.